# For loop is emailing one character per row in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been stuck on this problem for a while. My requirements are to email data from mySQL to a client. I took code from another page in my company's codebase that works when it is emailed.

[image]

The problem that I am encountering is that it is emailing only one character per row.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$message = "
                <br /><hr /><br /><table style='font-size: 12px; width:100%'>
                <tr>
                    <td td width='25%'><strong>Oligo Name</strong></td>
                    <td width='10%'><strong>Base</strong></td>
                    <td width='10%'><strong>Scale</strong></td>
                    <td width='10%'><strong>Mod</strong></td>
                    <td width='10%'><strong>Mod Position</strong></td>
                    <td style='word-break: break-all; width: 500px;'><strong>Oligo Sequence</strong></td>
                    <td width='15%' style='text-align: right'><strong>Price</strong></td>
                </tr>";
                $SampleID = 0;
                $maxrow = $OligoQty;
                for ($i; $i < $maxrow; $i++) {
                    if(trim($SampleName) == '' && trim($Sequence) == '')
                            continue;
                            // $SampleID++; 
                    $bases = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $Sequence); 
                    $seq_length = strlen($bases);
                    $message .= "
                                <tr>
                                <td width='200'>{$SampleIDS} . {$SampleName[$i]}</td>
                                <td width='40'>{$sequence_length[$i]}</td>
                                <td width='40'>{$SampleScale[$i]}</td>
                                <td width='40'>{$modification[$i]}</td>
                                <td width='40'>{$mod_position[$i]}</td>
                                <td style='word-break: break-all; width: 500px;'>{$Sequence[$i]}</td>
                            </tr>";
                                </tr>";
                }
```

When I remove the for loop, it prints out the row perfectly:

[image]

I believe there is something wrong with my for loop that is causing it to do that and I am not sure why. I hard coded $maxrow to 2 and that is why I am getting 2 rows for the email. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, it looks a little strange - you should be looping over an array. I would think your values would need to use the $i someplace, more like $SampleID[$i]. Where are you getting those variables from?

Comment: Hello @dgig, is usually has [$i] after those variables. I removed those to show how it would look like without the for loop. I still get one character per row regardless.

Comment: See, then what you are doing is looping over strings, not arrays. `$SampleScale` is not an array - php will let you call `$SampleScale[3]` on a string and print out the fourth character, which is what you are seeing. Remove your loop and the `[$i]`s and what result do you get?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I know that removing the loop and the [$i]s make it work (It is the last picture in my question). Your comment did help me understand that it was looping through the string! That really helped me out as I am comparing the code with another page that has the same code. I appreciate it

Comment: Ah okay. Very good, good luck.